# Will a modern Time Capsule work with 10.5?

Tags: backup, time-capsule, leopard

While at home for the holidays, I noticed that the old iMac is probably on its last legs. I'd like to get a Time Capsule so that the documents are backed up when the time comes. However, the thought crossed my mind that the old iMac with OS X 10.5 might not be compatible with the new Time Capsule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new Time Capsules require OS X 10.75 and later:
http://www.apple.com/airport-time-capsule/specs/

Your best option is to upload your documents online (Dropbox, Google Drive, etc.) as your 10.5 backup on an external drive say, may not restore to the current version of OS X.

Comment: Thanks, I was worried about that. Unfortunately, the computer stopped booting before I was able to order anything! I decided to get them a computer that wasn't 7 years old and data transfer from the old one. A hard drive for backups is the next present!

Answer (score 0):

Purchase an inexpensive USB external HD and either manually copy the user's data from iMac to HD, or do a Time Machine or [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) backup. Time Machine and Migration Assistant are a perfect pair for restoring older systems to new.

Be aware that in order to run Migration Assistant on a newer version of Mac OS X, the Time Machine source backup must be created on a Snow Leopard (10.6.8 latest) or later installation, so you will need to upgrade this Mac, if possible. You can purchase Snow Leopard from Apple for [$19.99](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard).